# How to execute stages in parallel with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I created a test pipeline to understand how the parallel feature works with Jenkins.
Here you can see the code:

```
node ('docker-slave') {

    stage('Source') {
        sh 'echo Downloading source code from GIT'
        sh 'sleep 3'
    }

    stage('Compile'){
        sh 'echo Compiling the code'
        sh 'sleep 3'
    }

    stage('Test') {
        parallel(
            stage ('Unit test') {
                sh 'echo Performing unit test'
                sh 'sleep 10'
            },
            stage ('Security test') {
                sh 'echo Performing security test'
                sh 'sleep 8'
            }
        )
        stage ('Integration test') {
            sh 'echo Performing integration test'
            sh 'sleep 8'
        }
    }

    stage('Release') {
        def release = input message: 'Release into production?',
          parameters: [booleanParam(defaultValue: false,
          description: 'Click on the box to release into prod', name: 'releasing')]

        if(release == true){
            sh 'echo release into Production'
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I execute it, I am getting the following error:

> ```
> Started by user Jenkins
> Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
> [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
> [Pipeline] node
> Running on docker-slave-00002e11zecvz on docker in /home/jenkins/workspace/my-pipe
> [Pipeline] {
> [Pipeline] stage
> [Pipeline] { (Source)
> [Pipeline] sh
> + echo Downloading source code from GIT
> Downloading source code from GIT
> [Pipeline] sh
> + sleep 3
> [Pipeline] }
> [Pipeline] // stage
> [Pipeline] stage
> [Pipeline] { (Compile)
> [Pipeline] sh
> + echo Compiling the code
> Compiling the code
> [Pipeline] sh
> + sleep 3
> [Pipeline] }
> [Pipeline] // stage
> [Pipeline] stage
> [Pipeline] { (Test)
> [Pipeline] stage
> [Pipeline] { (Unit test)
> [Pipeline] sh
> + echo Performing unit test
> Performing unit test
> [Pipeline] sh
> + sleep 10
> [Pipeline] }
> [Pipeline] // stage
> [Pipeline] stage
> [Pipeline] { (Security test)
> [Pipeline] sh
> + echo Performing security test
> Performing security test
> [Pipeline] sh
> + sleep 8
> [Pipeline] }
> [Pipeline] // stage
> [Pipeline] }
> [Pipeline] // stage
> [Pipeline] }
> [Pipeline] // node
> [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [null, null]
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:708)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:640)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:234)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:193)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
>   at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor280.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>   at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>   at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
>   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
>   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
>   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
>   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>   at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
>   at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
>   at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
>   at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
>   at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
>   at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
>   at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
>   at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:14)
>   at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
>   at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
>   at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
>   at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
>   at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor252.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>   at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
>   at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Outcome.resumeFrom(Outcome.java:73)
>   at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:166)
>   at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
>   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
>   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
>   at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:136)
>   at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
>   at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> Finished: FAILURE
> ```

It seems I am incorrectly using the parallel feature, because Unit and Security tests are being executed together. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a working version code based on yours.

**Code:**

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'MISC' }

    stages{
        stage('Source'){
            steps {
                sh 'echo Downloading source code from GIT'
                sh 'sleep 3'
            }
        }
        stage('Compile'){
            steps{
                sh 'echo Compiling the code'
                sh 'sleep 3'
            }
        }
        stage('Test'){
            parallel{
                stage ('Unit test') {
                    steps{
                        sh 'echo Performing unit test'
                        sh 'sleep 10'
                    }
                }
                stage ('Security test') {
                    steps{
                        sh 'echo Performing security test'
                        sh 'sleep 8'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Release') {
            steps{
                sh 'echo Performing release'
                sh 'sleep 8'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Related part of log:**

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] { (Branch: Unit test)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: Security test)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Unit test)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Security test)
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo Performing unit test
Performing unit test
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo Performing security test
Performing security test
[Pipeline] sh
+ sleep 10
+ sleep 8
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

**Flow in `BlueOcean` view:**

[image: BO view]